# A hook (`orm`) failed to load! for Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sails-mongo

Anyone can help??

error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error: Could not tear down the ORM hook.  Error details: Error: Consistency violation: Attempting to tear down a datastore (`default`) which is not currently registered with this adapter.  This is usually due to a race condition in userland code (e.g. attempting to tear down the same ORM instance more than once), or it could be due to a bug in this adapter.  (If you get stumped, reach out at http://sailsjs.com/support.)
    at Object.teardown (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\sails-mongo\lib\index.js:390:19)
    at D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline.js:758:27
    at D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3047:20
    at eachOfArrayLike (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1002:13)    at eachOf (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1052:9)
    at Object.eachLimit (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3111:7)    at Object.teardown (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline.js:742:11)
    at Hook.teardown (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\index.js:246:30)
    at Sails.wrapper (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\@sailshq\lodash\lib\index.js:3275:19)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at Sails.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at Sails.emitter.emit (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\sails\lib\app\private\after.js:56:26)
    at D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\sails\lib\app\lower.js:67:11
    at beforeShutdown (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\sails\lib\app\lower.js:45:12)    at Sails.lower (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\sails\lib\app\lower.js:49:3)
    at Sails.wrapper [as lower] (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\@sailshq\lodash\lib\index.js:3275:19)
    at whenSailsIsReady (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\sails\lib\app\lift.js:68:13)
    at D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3861:9    at D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:421:16    at iterateeCallback (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:924:17)
    at D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:906:16error:
error: Error: Consistency violation: Unexpected error creating db connection manager:
```
ImplementationError: Internal error occurred while running `createManager`.  Got non-Error: { MongoError: connection 0 to cluster0-shard-00-00-cqwe8.mongodb.net:27017 closed
    at Function.MongoError.create (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:29:11)
    at Socket. (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:202:22)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at TCP._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:557:12)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'connection 0 to cluster0-shard-00-00-cqwe8.mongodb.net:27017 closed' }

If you are the maintainer of "createManager", then you can change its implementation to solve the problem (Most of the time, the solution is just to throw an actual Error instance instead.  Alternatively, if the goal was to indicate a particular exception, you could throw any of the special, reserved "exit signals"-- e.g. the code name of any of your defined exits besides "error" or "success").  Otherwise, please file a bug report with the maintainer, or fork your own copy and fix that.
 [?] See https://sailsjs.com/support for help.
    at Object.registerDatastore (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\sails-mongo\lib\index.js:263:18)
    at D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline.js:714:27
    at D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3047:20
    at eachOfArrayLike (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1002:13)    at eachOf (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1052:9)
    at Object.eachLimit (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3111:7)    at Object.initialize (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline.js:650:11)
    at buildOntologyAndRunAutoMigrations (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\lib\build-ontology-and-run-auto-migrations.js:55:7)
    at async.auto._buildOntology (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\lib\initialize.js:456:7)
    at runTask (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1660:17)
    at D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1602:17
    at processQueue (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1612:17)
    at taskComplete (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1630:13)
    at D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1653:21
    at D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:339:31
    at D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:847:20
    at async.auto._checkAdapterCompatibility (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\lib\initialize.js:428:14)
    at runTask (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1660:17)
    at D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1602:17
    at processQueue (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1612:17)
    at taskComplete (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1630:13)
    at D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1653:21
```
    at Object.error (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\sails-mongo\lib\index.js:268:21)
    at D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\machine\lib\private\help-build-machine.js:1514:39
    at proceedToFinalAfterExecLC (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\parley\lib\private\Deferred.js:1149:14)
    at proceedToInterceptsAndChecks (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\parley\lib\private\Deferred.js:909:12)
    at proceedToAfterExecSpinlocks (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\parley\lib\private\Deferred.js:841:10)
    at D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\parley\lib\private\Deferred.js:303:7
    at D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\machine\lib\private\help-build-machine.js:952:35
    at Function.handlerCbs.error (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\machine\lib\private\help-build-machine.js:742:26)
    at connectCb (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\sails-mongo\lib\private\machines\create-manager.js:130:22)
    at connectCallback (D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:428:5)
    at D:\gcloud\test01-2\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:335:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)

Answer (score 0):

You should set config.datastore.default.adapter: 'sails-mongo'. Moreover, if you modified a model while there was data in the db you should drop it.